# Importing large CSV file into OrientDB

Tags: csv, import, orientdb

I am new to orient-db, so I am working with flight search graph database in Orient-db. I have millions of real flights data, I created `JSON` file to import the `csv` file but it takes hours and hours to import all the millions of data. It imports only around 500 row per second.

I used etl for importing the csv file.

Here is my json file

```
{
"source": {
    "file": {
        "path": "C:/Users/sams/Desktop/OrientDB2/flights.csv"
    }
},
"extractor": {
    "csv": {}
},
"transformers": [
    {
        "vertex": {
            "class": "Flight"
        }
    },
    {
        "edge":  
            {
                "class": "Has_Flight",
                "joinFieldName": "depart_airport_id",
                "lookup": "Airport.airport_id",
                "direction": "in"
            } 
    },
    {
        "edge":
        {
                "class": "Flying_To",
                "joinFieldName": "arrive_airport_id",
                "lookup": "Airport.airport_id",
                "direction": "out"
        }
    }

],
"loader": {
    "orientdb": {
        "dbURL": "plocal:C:/Users/sams/Desktop/OrientDB2/database/dataflight",
        "dbType": "graph",
        "dbAutoCreate": true,
        "classes": [
            {
                "name": "Airport",
                "extends": "V"
            },
            {
                "name": "Flight",
                "extends": "V"
            },
            {
                "name": "Has_Flight",
                "extends": "E"
            },
            {
                "name": "Flying_To",
                "extends": "E"
            }
        ],
        "indexes": [
            {
                "class": "Airport",
                "fields": [
                    "airport_id:integer"
                ],
                "type": "UNIQUE"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

So my question is, Is there any other mechanism for importing large-data set in Orient-db?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: sams which importer did you use? etl?
or did you write some code?

Comment: [tag:wolf4ood] just editing my question and am adding my etl configuration file (json file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to disable the WAL, enable txLog and usebatching.

Let's try that:

```
"wal" = false
"batchCommit" = 1000
"txUseLog" = true
```

Docs about OrientDb loader: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Loader.html#orientdb

Let me know if you find a combination that improve performances.